# How to delete a single Cloudinary image from browser?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

Here I am using `Cloudinary` Upload widget to upload images into cloudinry.
How can I delete a particular image from `Cloudinary` through browser(here I have image details like `public_id`,`imageName`,`url`,etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of publicId we can delete the image(s)/video(s)/etc.Below is the working code.

publicId    --- cloudinary publicId.

resourceType ---- image/video/raw

```
function deleteImage(publicId,resourceType,callback){ 
    console.log(resourceType);//image,video,raw

    cloudinary.api.delete_resources(publicId, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
         if(result.hasOwnProperty("error")){
             callback(result);
             return;
         }else{
              callback(result);

         }  
    },{all:true,resource_type:resourceType});   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sami is right, the `destroy` endpoint is indeed one way of deleting a resource, from the client-side, although it requires first generating a signature on the server-side.

Unsigned deletion is also available using the delete-token (resource-specific token, valid for 10 minutes from the time of upload), you can read more about it here: http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521132-How-to-delete-an-image-from-the-client-side-

Integrating the delete-token to the Upload-Widget is possible by setting the `Return delete token` to **true** in the upload-preset.
See: http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200788712-Upload-widget-how-to-get-delete-link-to-appear-next-to-thumbnails-?locale=en-us

Answer (score -2):

Try to read/understand the doc : 
[Delate an Image on Cloudinary - The Doc](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#deleting_images)